# PHP/Javascript/JSON login

Tags: php, javascript, authentication

I am trying to create a login using index.html, login.js and login.php.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/login.css">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../javascript/login.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../javascript/engine.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name="loginForm" autocomplete="off">
            <table align=center>
            <tr><td colspan=2 bgcolor=#87C9FF><center><h2>Login</h2></center></td></tr>
                <tr><td><label for="username">Username:</label></td><td><input id="username" name="username" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9]{3,3}" title="Minmimum 3 letters or numbers." required></td></tr>
                <tr><td><label for="password">Password:</label></td><td><input id="password" name="password" type="password" pattern=".{8,8}" title="Minmimum 8 letters or numbers." required></td></tr>
                <tr><td colspan=2><center><input type="submit" class="btn" value="Login" onClick="handleLogin(this.form)"></center></td></tr>
            </table>
        </form>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <div name="Details" class="Details" id="Details></div>
        <br/>
    <?php include 'footer.php'; ?>
    </body>
<html>
```

login.js

```
    jQuery(document).ready(
    function () {
        document.getElementById('username').focus().focus();
    }
);

function handleLogin(frm){
    var username = document.getElementById('username').value;
    var password = document.getElementById('password').value;
alert('hello');
    $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'login.php',
            data: {un: username, pw: password},
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            success: function(result) {
                validate = result;
                            alert("Goodbye");
            }   ,
    });
}
```

login.php

```
<?php

    $username = $_POST["un"];
    $password = $_POST["pw"];
    $username = strtoupper($username);
    $password = strtoupper($password);

    $file_handle = fopen("phplog.txt", "w");
    $file_contents = "Username:" . $username . "\r\nPassword:" . $password . "\r\n";

    # This section will open a connection to the existing backup server and get the last ith_rid used.
    # It will then store that ith_rid to be used later and then close the database connection 
    $mysqlconn = new mysqli('localhost','username','password', 'table');
    if ($mysqlconn->connect_errno) {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqlconn->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqlconn->connect_error;
    }

    $res = $mysqlconn->query("SELECT opr, password FROM us_f WHERE opr='" . $username ."' GROUP BY opr, password ORDER BY opr DESC");
    if (!$res) {                                            ##If there is an error running query, display it to the screen.
        echo "Error: $mysqlconn->error \n";
    }
    $num_rows = $res -> num_rows;
    $file_contents .= $num_rows . "\r\n";
    $file_contents .= "SELECT opr, password FROM us_f WHERE opr='" . $username ."' GROUP BY opr, password ORDER BY opr DESC\r\n";


    if ($num_rows > 0){
        $result = 1;
        fwrite($file_handle, $file_contents);
        fclose($file_handle);
        echo json_encode($result);
    }
    if ($num_rows == 0){
        $result = 0;
        fwrite($file_handle, $file_contents);
        fclose($file_handle);
        echo json_encode($result);
    }
    fwrite($file_handle, $file_contents);
    fclose($file_handle);
?>
```

I have tested login.php using GET instead of POST and passing variables through URL. I know this works and returns 1 if valid and 0 if not valid.

I have tested login.js because it will pop-up "Hello" when I click login.

What is happening is that once login.php sends the result back, I can't get anything to come up. For instance, the alert box "Goodbye" doesn't come up.

I can't determine if login.php is returning correctly or if login.js is handling the result correctly.

Answer (score 2):

logintest.html:

```
<form action="login.php" method=POST>
  Username<input type="text" name="username" /><br />
  Password<input type="password" name="password"<br />
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

1. Use a simple test form to test your PHP, taking javascript out of the equation.
2. Don't convert the password to uppercase, you're decreasing your effective security by roughly half.
3. Don't store your passwords in plain text!
4. ***Don't concatenate unvalidated user input into a SQL query.***

   - Consider the username: `BobbyTables' OR 1=1;--`
5. Don't log usernames and passwords to a file!
6. I don't understand the `GROUP BY` clauses in your queries, you're not using any aggregate functions.

Comment: Instead of answering someone's question, what I will do is assume they are complete idiots and point out minor things in their code even though it is a work in progress. Really, it is for their own good. They don't really want their question answered anyway. What they want is someone to lecture them about obvious things. I am completely not wasting their time by assuming I know their work environment and what their requirements are. After all, I have toured their site and am familiar with everything.

Comment: 1) I will assume that they haven't tried a simple test form. Clearly they are barely literate and have probably never touched a computer before. It couldn't possibly be that they tried a simple test form and found no issue.

Comment: 2) Seeing as how I have no idea what their requirements are for their environment, I will assume that they never need to convert to uppercase. In fact, I am going to go ahead and advise them to never user the upper case function in PHP. We should really get that stripped out anyway.

Comment: 3) Even though this is a work in progress, I feel it is very important for me to point out everything I find, whether I my opinion was solicited or not. Just the other day, I was walking through an OR and pointed out to the doctor that he needs to sew the patient back up. I feel as though I saved a life that day. If not for me, that stupid doctor would have never stitched the patient back up. It truly is a burden to be this smart.

Comment: 4) There really is no excuse for the code in progress to be anything but absolutely perfect. I mean, who wants to get something up and running and then go back later and fix all the details? I have never known anyone who wanted to get the prototype up so they can show progress. I am literally the only person who has ever heard of SQL injection and it is my lot in life to educate everyone.

Comment: 5) When creating anything, it is never good to have any thing in place to help you diagnose issues. I know that lesser mortals are tempted to put code in that will help them identify exactly which line isn't running correct, but they are just naive fools. Using a log file to determine what your php file is doing is just absurd. We all know that you are supposed to your use your copy of the Matrix to tap directly into the CPU to see the code as it is executed.

Comment: 6) If I don't understand something then it is clearly invalid until such time as I understand it. I have a special 1-800 number setup so programmers all over the world can call me for code verification. They aren't allowed to do anything that doesn't make sense to me. If you want your questioned answered, first you must explain ALL of your code to me. I have to make sure you are doing things the way I would do things. After all, my way is the only valid way.

Comment: @user1621308 Welp... have fun with that. :I

Comment: No, no, thank you. I have seen the light. My questions wasn't important anyway. Too much emphasis is put on applications that actually work. What really counts is that we don't use GROUP BY when it isn't necessary. My boss will understand that eventually.

Comment: @user1621308 Clearly the best option is to throw an internet tantrum, delete your code, attempt to deface my answer, and go on a 7-comment sarcasm rant instead of simply stating "Did that, here's the JSON output it produced, I'm still having problem X" and either ignoring my other niggling questions, or dismissing them with "yes, I know. those will be addressed later."

Comment: No, clearly the best option is to wake up, have a cup of coffee, read the morning paper, get dressed, drive into work, fire up the old computer, go to a site that is dedicated to helping people find answers to their problems, read their problem, completely ignore what they are asking, give them a bunch of "tips" they already knew because you just assume that no one could possible know the things contained in your brilliant mind and then in no way answer their question. That can only be followed by a smug sense of accomplishment that comes with helping no one.

Comment: Oh, by the way, I was able to figure out my issue on my own. I will not be posting the solution because I won't reward a site with content when it was counterproductive.

Comment: @Sammitch, Wow! After reading the rant I have to give you a +1 for the patience and wiki link, lol this made my day (two years after), too funny!